# Subquery returning multiple rows instead of one row

Tags: oracle

I have the following query, the query is supposed to return the latest score by looking first at this column (MAX_TEST) to see if it has a score, if it doesn't have a score then it looks at this column (MAX__SCORE), after it picks up the latest score, I need to alias it as  (PSI score). the second output show return the PSI Score- and aliased as  PSI XMation.  So far I am able to get the PSI Score to return the value but the PSI Xmation is not working, I get an error saying the from keyword is not where its supposed to be. The final issue is that I am getting multiple rows instead of just one row.

```
SELECT P_PI_NUM,
COALESCE(MAX_SCORE) AS PS
```

Comment: You want the last `WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F` record. From this you take the `MAX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST` if not null, otherwise the `MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE`? Yes? That's it? But how does `PARENT_PI_NUMBER` come into play? You are partitioning and grouping by it. Why? Please explain.

Comment: Parent PI has one to many relationship with the scores

Comment: You have not answered my questions. Whatever relation parent PI has with the scores, what does it have to do with the query? Why do use it? Why do you group by it?

Comment: to get the scores associated with each parent PI is the reason I am using it in the query, as for grouping , I don't have to group by parent if that will solve my problem and still give me the desired output

Comment: You said you were looking for the lastest score, which is in one particular record. And this has nothing to do with the `PARENT_PI_NUMBER`. Of course there is also the latest score per `PARENT_PI_NUMBER`, which may be many rows. Which of the two do you actually want? Or do you first want to get the latest score per `PARENT_PI_NUMBER` and from these pick one value (the greatest, smallest, earliest, ...)?

Comment: I am looking for latest score per parent PI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get the latest score per parent ID (standard SQL):

```
select 
  parent_pi_number,
  psi_score,
  (psi_score - 39.035024) / 8.439997 as psi_xmation
from
(
  select  
    parent_pi_number,
    coalesce(gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, psi_overall_score) as psi_score,
    row_number() over (partition by parent_pi_number
                       order by request_last_modified_dt desc) as rn
  from wc_application_event_f
  where pi_candidate_num = 69130
)
where rn = 1
order by parent_pi_number;
```

And here is another (Oracle only):

```
select  
  parent_pi_number,
  max(coalesce(gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, psi_overall_score)) 
      keep (dense_rank last order by request_last_modified_dt) 
    as psi_score,
  (max(coalesce(gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, psi_overall_score)) 
       keep (dense_rank last order by request_last_modified_dt) - 39.035024) / 8.439997 
    as psi_xmation
from wc_application_event_f
where pi_candidate_num = 69130
group by parent_pi_number
order by parent_pi_number;
```

(I hope I got your calculation with the parentheses right.)

Comment: none of the query are executing. I get this error ORA-00904: "MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE": invalid identifier

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the column names from your query. It must be the names without `MAX_`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: your last post seems to work. Thanks much. Now here is the weird part, or simply the problem, since a candidate can have multiple Parent PI, and  each score can be tagged to all the parent pi, how do I get it to just pick up one (the newest ) and display just one row? instead  of ,multiple rows of same values on the score

Comment: It seems I still don't understand. You said you want the latest score per parent PI. Now you say you just want one row. Only one of the two statements can be correct; they are contradicting each other. If you don't want the latest score per parent PI, but just the latest score, then remove `parent_pi_number` from the queries.

Comment: This fixed it. how do I mark it as answered by you?

Comment: There should be a gray checkmark next to my answer that you can click.